# Get all rows based on given date in web sql

Tags: javascript, sql, html, oracle-sqldeveloper, web-sql

I have a EVENTS Table with multiple Date columns (startDate, endDate). I need to query and get records based on a given date.
For example if i run my query with May 11th Saturday as endDate, it should return rows with ID 8 and 12

[image]

i tried with following queries but no result

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2019-05-09 00:00:00.00' AND '2019-05-09 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: Assuming the startDate is of type "Date" you'd have to use the To_Date sql method to format the date. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are stored as dates, you should be able to use:

```
WHERE startDate >= DATE '2019-05-09' AND
      startDate < DATE '2019-05-10'
```

However, your dates look like strings.  I would recommend first fixing the data model.  But, you can also use string operations:

```
WHERE startDate LIKE '%May 09 2019%'
```

Comment: Thanks. LIKE operator solved my issue. Actual problem is my date columns are not of type Date. its being inserted as string

Answer (score 0):

your data type for your date seems to be timestamp with given format. If you want to query to your database, you should first cast your string into timestamp or any data type of your desire.

For now, seems assuming your data type of your startDate and endDate is timestamp, try

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE startDate 
BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-09 00:00:00.00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-09 23:59:59.999','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFF')
```